# JDBC: jtds getString() returns doubles in scientific notation

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds, number-formatting

When using jtds JDBC driver, `getString` sometimes returns doubles formatted in the scientific notation:

```
// metaData.getColumnType(0) == java.sql.Types.DOUBLE
String.format("%f", resultSet.getDouble(0)); // = 26150279.910000
resultSet.getString(0);  // = 2.615027991E7
```

for some values it doesn't:

```
String.format("%f", resultSet.getDouble(0)); // = 624000.000000
resultSet.getString(0);  // = 624000.0
```

Is it possible to force `getString` to always return `%f`-formatted doubles?

**Please, don't persuade me to use `getDouble()`. Thank you.**

Answer (score 4):

Extract the double using getDouble:

```
double num = resultSet.getDouble();
```

Create a decimal formatter specifying the pattern you want to use. If you don't specify it, the default locale pattern is used:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
```

Obtain the formatted string

```
String formattedString = df.format(num);
```

And enjoy your own string :)

if you need help on how to build a pattern, refer to the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: thank you for your efforts. The question was how to make jtds formatting double in the same way for all the values.

Comment: i guess you can't change the behavior of a library, don't you think? i am sure this is the best way. Just define a single DecimalFormat and format all of your doubles with that.

Comment: Agreed, I can't change the behavior. Now I need to understand why database column type `decimal(28,2)` becomes `double` in jdbc.

Comment: what type are you expecting exactly? i mean, if you use getDouble you'll get a double, getString you'll get a string, getFloat gives a float, and so on...

Comment: What i mean is, the association decimal(28,2) -> double is not dependent on jdbc but on the getTYPE() method you're using.